# How to modify and show a queue in a WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, queue

I'm trying to show in a TextBox in a Windows Presentation Foundation a queue after adding some items, I know it must be something simple, I've checked the code with a breakpoint, the Add Item button works good but once I press it again the queue is empty and I'm always adding just an item and once I add it and I press the same button Add Item button again or the Show Button the queue is empty, I would like to add items and show the queue with the items I added, I made a class named QueueClas. Here below is all the code, thanks beforehand!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Queue2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
            public MainWindow()
            {

            InitializeComponent();
            QueueClas queuec = new QueueClas();  
            buttonAdd.Click += ButtonAdd_Click;
            buttonShow.Click += ButtonShow_Click;
        }

        private void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            QueueClas queuec = new QueueClas();
            textBoxShow.Text = queuec.ShowQueue();
        }


        private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            QueueClas queuec = new QueueClas();
            queuec.AddQueue(int.Parse(textBoxQueue.Text));
            textBoxQueue.Clear();                
        }

       public class QueueClas
        {
            Queue<int> myqueue;
            public QueueClas()
            {
                myqueue = new Queue<int> { };
            }
            public void AddQueue(int x)
            {
                myqueue.Enqueue(x);                
            }
            public string ShowQueue()
            {
                return string.Join(" ", myqueue);
            }
            public void DeleteItem(int x)
            {
                myqueue.Dequeue();
            }
            public string NumberOfItems()
            {
                int counter = 0;
                counter = myqueue.Count();
                return "The queue contains " + counter.ToString() + " elements";
            }
            public string MinQueue()
            {
                return "The minimun value of the queue is: " + myqueue.Min().ToString();
            }
            public string MaxQueue()
            {
                return "The maximum value of the queue is: " + myqueue.Max().ToString();
            }
            public string FindElement(int x)
            {
                foreach (int item in myqueue)
                {
                    if (x == item)
                    {
                        return "The item is in the queue";
                    }
                }
                return "The item is not in the queue";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the add and show buttons you are initialising your list with `QueueClas queuec = new QueueClas();`. This is completely erasing the list ans starting fresh. You already initialise it in your `MainWindow` constructor so there's no need to do it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that in both buttons it doesn`t recognize the object  "queuec"  from the  MainWindow  constructor, I obtain a new error:    The name 'queuec' doesn`t exist in the current context.    I know it must be something simple but I can`t find why this is happening...

Comment: @Alexander Since you instantiate queuec as a local variable of MainWindow constuctor, after the constructor, it will be inaccessible (and gabage collected later). You should instantiate it as a class member of MainWindow to make it accessible during the lifetime of the class.

Comment: Voila!! Thanks a lot emoacht the error was in there!! Have a good night!!